# passportjs middleware not in use error - using expressjs, bookshelf, express-session

Tags: express, passport.js, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to implement the passport.js module with sqlite3/bookshelf.js modules. This is my partial code:

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret cat',
  proxy: true,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
 }));

 var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users'
 });

var passport = require('passport'), LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  new User().where({username: username, password: password}).fetch()
  .then(function(user){
    if (user === null) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
    }
    return done(null, user.toJSON());
  });
}));

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }));
```

And here are all my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
 "bluebird": "^2.9.14",
 "body-parser": "~1.10.2",
 "bookshelf": "^0.7.9",
 "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
 "debug": "~2.1.1",
 "express": "~4.11.1",
 "express-session": "^1.10.4",
 "hbs": "~2.8.0",
 "knex": "^0.7.6",
 "morgan": "~1.5.1",
 "passport": "^0.2.1",
 "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
 "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
 "sqlite3": "^3.0.5"
}
```

If I write wrong username and password I get redirected correctly. However, if I login with my right data, I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use 
at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ah, just found it docs: In a Connect or Express-based application, passport.initialize() middleware is required to initialize Passport.

http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/